# Can set axis with decimal power of 10?

Tags: matlab

Now I have a list of y values:
7.0225
6.9155
7.2565
60.40775
1138.0016
1151.35275
1155.268667.

I want to set the ytick with the form of power of 10. For those y values above, it's hard to set a proper limit. I wonder if it's possible that 10^c and c is a decimal (e.g.: 10^-0.1, 10^0.2, 10^0.5).

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [`semilogy`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html). Is this what you needed?

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.